# ¿Como ordenar este array de arrays en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, ordenamiento, jsonarray, sortable

tengo el siguiente array de arrays.

```
let data = [["Regular", "Estado"], ["Registrado","Condición"], ["Regular","Vigente"]]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenarlo por palabra, me explico que el que tiene la palabra Registrado sean los primeros array en mostrarse y los que contengan la palabra Regular sean los últimos en verse, algo asi:

```
let data = [["Registrado","Condición"], ["Regular", "Estado"], ["Regular","Vigente"]]
```

Para poder tenerlo definido de esa forma y si ingresan más arrays pues haya una prioridad de acuerdo a un string que indique

Comment: Los quieres ordenar por orden alfabética o según tus propios criterios ?

Comment: Es de acuerdo a mi propio criterio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método sort del objeto array:

```
data.sort((a,b)=>{
  if(a[0]=="Registrado")
      return -1
  else
      return a[1]>b[1]?1:-1
})
```

La parte de else permite que se ordenen también por el segundo valor.
**EDITO**
Si quieres agrupar los Registrado pero manteniendo el orden la función sería

```
   data.sort((a,b)=>{
        if(a[0]=="Registrado")
             return (b[0]==a[0]?0;-1)
        } 
   )
```

De esta manera cuando encuentra dos registrados seguidos no los intercambia (return 0).

Comment: En este caso solo quiero que se ordene en base al primer elemento del array, los demás elementos que no se vean afectados , en ese caso solo usaria el IF , correcto ?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para ajustarla a esta condición (que no ordene, solo agrupe)

Answer (score 0):

He realizado una función que usa el sort del prototipo Array, esta función recibe como parámetro el array y un "order" que es un string (la palabra que quieres que aparezca de primero al momento de order).

```
 function OrderBy(array, order){
  return array.sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a[0] == order) {
      return -1;
    }
  });
}
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
let dataSort = orderBy(array,"Registrado");
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! , he probado el codigo que me compartes y en el caso de "Registrado" que solamente es un array que lo contiene lo ordena de forma correcta, pero por ejemplo colocando "Regular", deberian pasar los arrays con esa palabra a estar primeros y al final el array que contiene registrado pero no funciona en ese caso.

Comment: Tienes razón, eso estoy revisando voy a modificarlo...